# Custom Paging in Telerik MVC Razor Grid-Causes Performance issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, telerik

I am using Telerik MVC grid, in which I am trying to populate around 3,00,000 records. While fetching these through service takes little time and while populating it gives performance issue.
so I decided to go with Custom paging.so it loads only one page data at a time,but it takes very long time to split the Page using Total Recordcount.

Here is my code. Please help me in this.

```
[GridAction(EnableCustomBinding=true,GridName="RunDetails")]
        public ActionResult RunDetails(string id, GridCommand command)
        {            
            var run = service.GetAllRuns().First(x => x.ID == id);
            var itemList = new List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>() ;
            try
            {                

                var detail = service.GetStatistic(run);
                itemList = detail.Select(x => ((object)x.Inner).ToExpando()).ToList();
                if (command.Page == 0 && command.PageSize == 0)
                {
                    command.Page=1;
                    command.PageSize = 20;
                }
                ViewData["total"] = itemList.Count; 
                 itemList = itemList.Skip((command.Page - 1) * command.PageSize).Take(command.PageSize).ToList();


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error("Error while changing the state of the Run = " + e);
            }
            return View(new StatisticRunModel(run, itemList));

        }

    **VIEW:**
      @{
        Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Items)
        .Name("RunDetails")
        .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(x => x))
        .EnableCustomBinding(true)
        .BindTo(Model.Items)        
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            if (Model.Columns != null)
            {
                foreach (var col in Model.Columns)
                {
                    if (!col.Contains("ID"))
                    {
                    string colname = col.ToString();
                    columns.Bound(colname);
                    }                  
                }

                }
            })
        .Sortable(sorting => sorting.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
        .Filterable()
        .Pageable(settings => settings.Total((int)ViewData["total"]).PageSize(20))
        //.Pageable(paging => paging//.Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom)
                            //.Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric)
                            //.Total((int)ViewData["total"])
                            //.PageSize(20)) //this also causing same problem

        .Render();
}
```

Comment: what does this method returns service.GetStatistic(run);. Dont return list instead return IQueryable

Comment: here i got the issue when i try to bind 20 records.its creating page for my 3,00,000 records,this makes the issue.

Comment: .Pageable(settings => settings.Total(20))... did you try this?